# No use after extend AlertDialog and rewrite dispatchKeyEvent method

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to disable the global search key when display the alertDialog. So I extents the class and rewrite the method dispatchKeyEvent to catch the key message. But when I press search key in the AlertDialog window, it cannot catch the key event. Why?

Here is the code in the new dispatchKeyEvent method:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)
        return true;
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this in my app ans it works. Could you provide your custom dialog sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to solve this. Not to extend the AlertDialog but extend the Builder instead. And in the constructor write the code below:

```
   setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

    });
```

And this can catch the global search key and drop it.